# Sort by joined column with Pageable

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have next method in JPARepository

```
@Query("select d from User u JOIN u.documents d WHERE u.id=:userId")
Page<Document> getDocuments(@Param("userId") String userId, Pageable pageable);
```

result sql query looks like

```
select **document-properties** from _User user0_ inner join ... where user0_.id=? order by user0_.name asc limit ?
```

Page size constraint works fine. But sort applies to the user (u) not to the document (d). How to apply sorting to joined column?

Comment: Have you looked here? [Check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903774/ordering-a-join-fetched-collection-in-jpa-using-jpql-hql) it looks very similar to your issue. from what I remember, I don't think you can order by internal collection properties.

Answer (score 0):

1)First of all check if the response doesn't return several identical values.
2)Put @OrderBy() annotation for Document collection. In this case you ought to refactor a little your code.

Good luck